# CSS background color comes out of the box

Tags: html, css, color-picker

I am having a small problem with the CSS of the jQuery colorPicker plugin trigger box. It uses a background image. When you click on the color trigger box and select any color, it shows that color as background of the trigger box. But the background color seems to come out of the box which makes it look like border of same color.

The background image size is 22x22px, I can somehow overcome this problem by defining the height and width of the box smaller than 22px, but that hides part of the image also, and I do not wish to do that. I would like to keep the original size of image (ie. 22px).

Here is the jsfiddle link, since its a plugin and has lots of extra code, so I am not pasting it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/HaFDF/1/

Here you can see the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've just had a play with the jsFiddle and it looks like the border is a semi-transparent part of the image. It's not hard to get round this - you simply clip the image as you said (I clipped to 20px to remove all 4 borders) and then re-apply the border using CSS.

I've mocked this up with a #777 border here: http://jsfiddle.net/HaFDF/3/

Comment: OOPS! Awkward....maybe an ajax update feature when there's a new answer could have stopped this happening!

Answer (score 1):

That's just because the style was created for. The plugin is using a background image centered (both verticaly and horizontally). What you can do is make your picker littler to hide this thin border (use 20*20 instead of 22*22), and put your own border.

If you don't want this color, use this css for `miniColors-trigger` :

```
.miniColors-trigger {
    height: 20px; //reduced from 22 to 20
    width: 20px; //reduced from 22 to 20
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0; //put whatever you want
    background: url('http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/images/trigger.png') center no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 .25em;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}
```

[Jsfiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/HaFDF/2/)